# When posting images using my facebook-like system, it shows the same image on every post

Tags: html, mysql, web, blob

I'm creating a status posting system, similar to the one Facebook has to offer. But, I've run into a bit of a pickle with the images. When I post a status with an image, it literally displays the same image on all of the statuses and posting a new image, it doesn't change at all. I attempted to use an if statement in the postimage.php file (below) to check whether there was an image in that row, but it seems to not have worked at all, and now actually broken the entire thing as to where it won't display the image at all anymore, even if I remove the if statement. So, I really have no clue what's going on here if anyone could lend some assistance, would be great.

**Code on my page to display image**

```
        <div class="postimages">
    <?php
    $imgsrc="postimage.php?id={$id}";
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>" />
    </div>
```

**Postimage.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();

$idpost = $_SESSION['idpost'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$idpost";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['pictures'];
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` should be `$_GET`, since you pass the the id as a GET-parameter. And your query is vulnerable to SQL-injection, have a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) (enough examples on that page)

Comment: No, i've sent the id in a session variable

Comment: And i'm not worried about SQL-injection at the moment, I just need something that looks good and then I can work on fixing it up later.

Comment: This `postimage.php?id={$id}` really looks like a GET-parameter to me